# libjpeg decompress to RAW not working

Tags: c, jpeg, libjpeg, file-conversion

I am on a RHEL 6.0 x86_64 box with the following version of libjpeg.

```
[mehoggan@hogganz400 jpeg_to_raw.c]$ rpm -qa libjpeg
libjpeg-6b-46.el6.x86_64
```

I have the following code which takes as its input a .jpeg file, and writes out a .raw file. When I run the program the size of the file expands, which leads me to believe the program is working:

```
[mehoggan@hogganz400 jpeg_to_raw.c]$ ls -l
total 600
-rwxrwxr-x 1 mehoggan mehoggan  10113 Dec  1 10:32 jpeg_to_raw
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mehoggan mehoggan   3311 Dec  1 10:32 jpeg_to_raw.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mehoggan mehoggan     75 Dec  1 10:27 Makefile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mehoggan mehoggan 215205 Dec  1 09:19 test.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mehoggan mehoggan 374850 Dec  1 10:32 test_out.raw
```

However when I open up the file using Irfanview (and associated plugins) only a small portion of my image opens up. The code can be found below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <jpeglib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* we will be using this uninitialized pointer later to store raw, uncompressd image */
unsigned char *raw_image = NULL;
unsigned int size;

/**
 * print the information for what was stored in the JPEG File
 **/
void print_jpeg_info(struct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo)
{
    printf("JPEG File Information: \n");
    printf("Image width and height: %d pixels and %d pixels.\n", cinfo.image_width, cinfo.image_height);
    printf("Color components per pixel: %d.\n", cinfo.num_components);
    printf("Color space: %d.\n", cinfo.jpeg_color_space);
    printf("Raw flag is: %d.\n", cinfo.raw_data_out);
}

/**
 * read_jpeg_file Reads from a jpeg file on disk specified by filename and saves into the
 * raw_image buffer in an uncompressed format.
 *
 * \returns positive integer if successful, -1 otherwise
 * \param *filename char string specifying the file name to read from
 **/
int read_jpeg_file(char *filename)
{
    /* these are standard libjpeg structures for reading(decompression) */
    struct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;
    struct jpeg_error_mgr jerr;
    /* libjpeg data structure for storing one row, that is, scanline of an image */
    JSAMPROW row_pointer[1];
    FILE *infile = fopen(filename, "rb");
    unsigned long location = 0;
    int i = 0;
    if (!infile) {
        printf("Error opening jpeg file %s\n!", filename);
        return -1;
    }
    /* here we set up the standard libjpeg error handler */
    cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error(&jerr);
    /* setup decompression process and source, then read JPEG header */
    jpeg_create_decompress(&cinfo);
    /* this makes the library read from infile */
    jpeg_stdio_src(&cinfo, infile);
    /* reading the image header which contains image information */
    jpeg_read_header(&cinfo, TRUE);
    print_jpeg_info(cinfo);
    jpeg_start_decompress(&cinfo);

    /* allocate memory to hold the uncompressed image */
    size = cinfo.output_width*cinfo.output_height*cinfo.num_components;
    raw_image = (unsigned char*)malloc(size);
    /* now actually read the jpeg into the raw buffer */
    row_pointer[0] = (unsigned char *)malloc(cinfo.output_width*cinfo.num_components);
    /* read one scan line at a time */
    while (cinfo.output_scanline < cinfo.image_height) {
        jpeg_read_scanlines( &cinfo, row_pointer, 1 );
        for (i=0; i<cinfo.image_width*cinfo.num_components;i++) {
            raw_image[location++] = row_pointer[0][i];
        }
    }
    /* wrap up decompression, destroy objects, free pointers and close open files */
    jpeg_finish_decompress(&cinfo);
    jpeg_destroy_decompress(&cinfo);
    free(row_pointer[0]);
    fclose(infile);
    /* yup, we succeeded! */
    return 1;
}

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        char *infilename = "test.jpg";
        if (read_jpeg_file(infilename) > 0) {
            size_t count = size / sizeof(unsigned char*);
            fprintf(stdout, "The number of unsigned chars in raw_image = %d\n", (int)count);
            FILE *ofile = fopen("test_out.raw", "w+");
            ssize_t data_out = fwrite(raw_image, count, sizeof(unsigned char), ofile);
            fprintf(stdout, "%d", (int)data_out);
            fclose(ofile);
        }
        else 
            return -1;
        return 0;
    }
```

What is your take on why the program is not writing out all the data? Or why is it possibly corrupting the data?

The makefile used to build this simple app is:

```
jpeg_to_raw : jpeg_to_raw.c
    gcc jpeg_to_raw.c -Wall -o jpeg_to_raw -ljpeg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

size_t count = size / sizeof(unsigned char*);

gets you only 1/4 of the raw-data written (actually, in 64 bit mode only 1/8th).
count should be same as size (counting chars, not pointers)